# To what CEFR does SFI correspond?

Tags: sweden, language, language-test

The first time I lived in Sweden I did a 4-month language course at university.  The second time I lived in Sweden I wanted to continue with [*Svensk för invandrare* (Swedish for immigrants, SFI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swedish_for_immigrants) but I was declined because I had already reached the highest level for the courses on offer from the municipality, so I briefly did a Swedish course at a *Folkhögskola* instead.  However, I have never tested my level according to [CEFR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_European_Framework_of_Reference_for_Languages) scales.  Does the final SFI level correspond to any particular level within CEFR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [The Swedish Teacher](http://www.theswedishteacher.com/swedish-language-exams.html),

- SFI course A corresponds to CEFR level A1,
- SFI course B corresponds to CEFR level A1/A2,
- SFI course C corresponds to CEFR level A2/A2 +,
- SFI course D corresponds to CEFR B1/B1+.

Comment: I see.  That confirms my experience that finishing SFI does not really mean one knows Swedish particularly well.

Comment: I don’t know whether they exist for Swedish, but I have found online free “sample” versions of the “official” tests for Spanish, Italian, and other languages.